# Spark Cassandra Java Connection NoSuchMethodError or NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

From Spark Java App submitted to the Spark Cluster hosted on my machine, I am trying to connect to a Cassandra DB hosted on my machine @ 127.0.0.1:9042 and my Spring Boot application is failing to start.

**Approach 1 -**

** Based on the Spark-Cassandra-Connector [link](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md) I had included the below in the POM file -**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Approach 1 - NoSuchMethodError - Log File:**

```
16/09/08 15:12:50 ERROR SpringApplication: Application startup failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.datastax.driver.core.KeyspaceMetadata.getMaterializedViews()Ljava/util/Collection;
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchTables$1(Schema.scala:281)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:305)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1$2.apply(Schema.scala:304)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$map$2.apply(TraversableLike.scala:683)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashSet1.foreach(HashSet.scala:316)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.immutable.HashSet$HashTrieSet.foreach(HashSet.scala:972)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.map(TraversableLike.scala:682)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.com$datastax$spark$connector$cql$Schema$$fetchKeyspaces$1(Schema.scala:304)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:325)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$$anonfun$fromCassandra$1.apply(Schema.scala:322)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:122)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withClusterDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:111)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector$$anonfun$withSessionDo$1.apply(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.closeResourceAfterUse(CassandraConnector.scala:140)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withSessionDo(CassandraConnector.scala:110)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector.withClusterDo(CassandraConnector.scala:121)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.fromCassandra(Schema.scala:322)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.Schema$.tableFromCassandra(Schema.scala:342)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.tableDef(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:50)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef$lzycompute(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.tableDef(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableRowReaderProvider$class.verify(CassandraTableRowReaderProvider.scala:137)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.verify(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:60)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD.getPartitions(CassandraTableScanRDD.scala:232)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:875)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:873)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
    at com.initech.myapp.cassandra.service.CassandraDataService.getMatches(CassandraDataService.java:45)
    at com.initech.myapp.processunit.MySparkApp.receive(MySparkApp.java:120)
    at com.initech.myapp.processunit.MySparkApp.process(MySparkApp.java:61)
    at com.initech.myapp.processunit.MySparkApp.run(MySparkApp.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.initech.myapp.MySparkAppBootApp.main(MyAppProcessingUnitsApplication.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
16/09/08 15:12:50 INFO AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3381b4fc: startup date [Thu Sep 08 15:12:40 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

**Approach 2 -**

** Since what I am developing is a Java Spark app, I thought of using the Spark-Cassandra-Connector-Java and had included the below in the POM file -**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

and ended up with this

**Approach 2 - SelectableColumnRef NoClassDefFoundError - Log File:**

16/09/08 16:28:07 ERROR SpringApplication: Application startup failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/SelectableColumnRef
    at com.initech.myApp.cassandra.service.CassandraDataService.getMatches(CassandraDataService.java:41)

** My Spark Main method calls the process() method below**

```
    public boolean process() throws InterruptedException {

    logger.debug("In the process() method");

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My Process Unit");

    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
    sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.port","9042");

    logger.debug("SparkConf = " + sparkConf);

    JavaStreamingContext javaStreamingContext = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));

    logger.debug("JavaStreamingContext = " + javaStreamingContext);

    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = javaStreamingContext.sparkContext();

    logger.debug("Java Spark context = " + javaSparkContext);

    JavaRDD<MyData> myDataJavaRDD = receive(javaSparkContext);

    myDataJavaRDD.foreach(myData -> {
        logger.debug("myData = " + myData);
    });

    javaStreamingContext.start();
    javaStreamingContext.awaitTermination();

    return true; }
```

** which calls the receive() below **

```
    private JavaRDD<MyData> receive(JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext) {
    logger.debug("receive method called...");

    List<String> myAppConfigsStrings = myAppConfiguration.get();
    logger.debug("Received ..." + myAppConfigsStrings);

    for(String myAppConfigStr : myAppConfigsStrings)
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        MyAppConfig myAppConfig;
        try {

            logger.debug("Parsing the myAppConfigStr..." + myAppConfigStr);

            myAppConfig = mapper.readValue(myAppConfigStr, MyAppConfig.class);

            logger.debug("Parse Complete...");

            // Check for matching data in Cassandra
            JavaRDD<MyData> cassandraRowsRDD = cassandraDataService.getMatches(myAppConfig, javaSparkContext);

            cassandraRowsRDD.foreach(myData -> {
                logger.debug("myData = " + myData);
            });

            return cassandraRowsRDD;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

** Eventually calling the Cassandra Data Service getMatches() below **

```
@Service    
public class CassandraDataService implements Serializable {    

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CassandraDataService.class);    

    public JavaRDD<MyData> getMatches(MyAppConfig myAppConfig, JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext) {    

        logger.debug("Creating the MyDataID...");    

        MyDataID myDataID = new MyDataID();    
        myDataID.set...(myAppConfig.get...);    
        myDataID.set...(myAppConfig.get...);    
        myDataID.set...(myAppConfig.get...);    

        logger.debug("MyDataID = " + myDataID);    

        JavaRDD<MyData> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(javaSparkContext).cassandraTable("myKeySpace", "myData", mapRowTo(MyData.class));    

        cassandraRowsRDD.foreach(myData -> {    
            logger.debug("====== Cassandra Data Service ========");    
            logger.debug("myData = " + myData);    
            logger.debug("====== Cassandra Data Service ========");    
        });    

        return cassandraRowsRDD;    
    }    
}
```

Has anyone experienced similar error or could provide me in some direction?
I have tried googling and reading through several items - but none to rescue. Thanks.

**Update 9/9/2016 2:15 PM PST**

I tried the approach above. Here is what I have done -

1. Spark cluster running with 1 worker thread
2. Submitted my Spark App using the Spring Boot Uber Jar using spark-submit command below -

   ```
   ./bin/spark-submit --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --master spark://localhost:6066 --deploy-mode cluster /Users/apple/Repos/Initech/Officespace/target/my-spring-spark-boot-streaming-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   ```
3. The Spark Driver program started successfully and initiated my Spark App and was set to "WAITING" state as there was only one worker running that was allocated to the driver program
4. I then started another worker thread and then the App worker thread had failed because of "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition". Below is the stack trace.

If it is useful in anyway - he is the stack I am using

```
1. cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.2.7 | CQL spec 3.3.1
2. Spark - 2.0.0
3. Spring Boot - 1.4.0.RELEASE
4. Jar's listed in the Approach 1 above
```

Exception Stack Tracke

```
    16/09/09 14:13:24 ERROR SpringApplication: Application startup failed
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:792)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:779)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at com.initech.officespace.MySpringBootSparkApp.main(MySpringBootSparkApp.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 192.168.0.30): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1450)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1438)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1437)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1659)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1618)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1607)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1871)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1884)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1897)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1911)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:875)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(RDD.scala:873)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:358)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.foreach(RDD.scala:873)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:350)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.AbstractJavaRDDLike.foreach(JavaRDDLike.scala:45)
        at com.initech.officespace.cassandra.service.CassandraDataService.getMatches(CassandraDataService.java:43)
        at com.initech.officespace.processunit.MyApp.receive(MyApp.java:120)
        at com.initech.officespace.processunit.MyApp.process(MyApp.java:61)
        at com.initech.officespace.processunit.MyApp.run(MyApp.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.partitioner.CassandraPartition
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1620)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1521)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1781)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:253)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    16/09/09 14:13:24 INFO AnnotationConfigApplicationContext: Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3381b4fc: startup date [Fri Sep 09 14:10:40 PDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
```

**Update 2 on 9/9/2016 3:20 PM PST**

Issue is now resolved based on the answer provided by RussS @ [Issues with datastax spark-cassandra connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36710478/issues-with-datastax-spark-cassandra-connector)

After updating my spark-submit to the below, I am seeing that the worker is able to pickup the connecter and start working on the RDDs :)

```
./bin/spark-submit --class org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --master spark://localhost:6066 --deploy-mode cluster  --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3  /Users/apple/Repos/Initech/Officespace/target/my-spring-spark-boot-streaming-app-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: Approach 1 is correct. Approach 2 is including an old version of the java api (as it is now bundled in the main SCC module) and should have a lot of issue.

Inorder to help more can you indicate how you are launching your spark application?

Comment: @RussS Made some progress and was able to get it working now based on your previous answers. Thanks.

Comment: @RussS.. I am now facing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28186607/java-lang-classcastexception-using-lambda-expressions-in-spark-job-on-remote-ser while performing spark-submit.. I have added my own jar and the spark-cassandra-connector to the --packages already.. but, that did not resolve anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solution could be different.

I had this exception when tried to run spark with cassandra from PC(driver) on java.

You can add jar with spark-cassandra-connector to SparkContext in my case it was like in example below:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    sc.addJar("./build/libs/spark-cassandra-connector_2.11-2.4.2.jar"); // location of driver could be different.
```

Answer (score -1):

`com.datastax.driver.core.KeyspaceMetadata.getMaterializedViews` is present starting version 3.0 of the driver.

Try adding this dependency to version 1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Due to the way Spark includes Guava it is now impossible to include the driver as an external dependency. The Driver is now included as a fat jar with the maven artifact.